# Optimising expensive join/subquery by filtering with conditionals

Tags: postgresql, join

This is a question about short-circuiting expensive JOINs or sub-queries in Postgresql (9.5 or 9.6). I'm also be interested in hearing how people in general solve the check-then-execute problem.

I'm writing a lot of queries that should only conditionally return a result, such as if the (web) user owns the record or if the record was modified. I'm trying to prevent building expensive views inside Postgresql and multiple back-and-forth queries to check for conditions in the application itself, so I attempt to write queries that first select the correct record and show which conditions failed, and only execute the view if the conditions pass.

For instance, this checks if the (application) user owns a record before returning it:

```
SELECT is_owner, is_newer, json 
FROM (
     SELECT id, owner = '053bffbc-c41e-dad4-853b-ea91fc42ea18' "is_owner"
          , modified >= created "is_newer" 
     FROM datasets 
     WHERE id = '056e4eed-ee63-2add-e981-0c86b8b6a66f'
) cond
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
     SELECT id 
     FROM datasets 
     WHERE is_owner and is_newer
) authed
    ON cond.id = authed.id
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
     SELECT json 
     FROM view_dataset 
     WHERE id = authed.id
) dataset
    ON true;
```

Resulting in (is owner):

```
is_owner | is_newer | json
t          t          {...}
```

And a negative result (not owner):

```
is_owner | is_newer | json
f          t          NULL
```

So the application knows which error to return but we don't have to build or parse the view if the conditions don't pass.

However, EXPLAIN ANALYSE shows **Postgresql still executes the view query in the last LEFT LATERAL JOIN even though the middle JOIN doesn't have any results**, and I can't get it to short-circuit to prevent the (expensive) view_dataset SELECT from running. If I set `json` to `null` the query skips everything but the first SELECT; but if it is set to a value from the last query, it will always execute all SELECTs, so I guess the query planner thinks it has to get a result for that `json` field in the top SELECT query and doesn't short-circuit the JOINs.

I wonder if I can force Postgresql to drop the expensive view query.

I have also tried a CTE, which does seem to skip the JOIN query:

```
WITH cond as (
    SELECT id, owner = '053bffbc-c41e-dad4-853b-ea91fc42ea18' "is_owner", modified >= created "is_newer" FROM datasets WHERE id = '056e4eed-ee63-2add-e981-0c86b8b6a66f'
)
SELECT cond.id, cond.is_owner, cond.is_newer, json FROM
    (SELECT id FROM cond WHERE cond.is_owner and cond.is_newer) filtered
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    (SELECT id, json from view_dataset) dataset
    USING (id)
    RIGHT JOIN cond
    USING(id);
```

... but this query and variations are at least 2x slower.

So my question is how to maximise performance by short-circuiting JOINs or subqueries based on conditions; and I'm also interested to hear if somebody has other ideas how to implement some check-first-then-execute pattern such as checking for record ownership.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may find some interest in the following article by https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2512/lukas-eder : https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/

Comment: What happens if you change: `) dataset ON true;` to `) dataset ON is_owner;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why `authed` is needed at all. What does:

```
SELECT is_owner, is_newer, json 
FROM (
     SELECT id, owner = '053bffbc-c41e-dad4-853b-ea91fc42ea18' "is_owner"
          , modified >= created "is_newer" 
     FROM datasets 
     WHERE id = '056e4eed-ee63-2add-e981-0c86b8b6a66f'
) cond
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
     SELECT json 
     FROM view_dataset 
     WHERE id = cond.id
) dataset
    ON is_owner and is_newer;
```

by you? I also agree with the comment made by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name). LATERAL can be a tremendous help for pushing predicates down to the base tables in special cases, but it is just a sub-query in disguise so in most cases it makes more sense to do an ordinary join. Do also try:

```
SELECT is_owner, is_newer, json 
FROM (
     SELECT id, owner = '053bffbc-c41e-dad4-853b-ea91fc42ea18' "is_owner"
          , modified >= created "is_newer" 
     FROM datasets 
     WHERE id = '056e4eed-ee63-2add-e981-0c86b8b6a66f'
) cond
LEFT JOIN view_dataset wd
    ON wd.id = cond.id 
   AND cond.is_owner 
   AND cond.is_newer;
```

**EDIT. table valued function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_view_dataset(int,bool) 
    RETURNS setof view_dataset AS '
        SELECT * 
        FROM view_dataset wd
        WHERE wd.id = $1 
          AND $2;
    ' LANGUAGE SQL;
```

and then use that function in your query as:

```
SELECT is_owner, is_newer, json 
FROM (
     SELECT id, owner = '053bffbc-c41e-dad4-853b-ea91fc42ea18' "is_owner"
          , modified >= created "is_newer" 
     FROM datasets 
     WHERE id = '056e4eed-ee63-2add-e981-0c86b8b6a66f'
) cond
LEFT JOIN get_view_dataset(cond.id, cond.is_owner AND cond.is_newer);
```

All untested.

Comment: Additionally: a lateral join is not necessarily faster. I would also try `left join view_dataset as dataset on dataset.id = cond.id and cond.is_owner and cond.is_newer`

Comment: I agree, I updated my answer. If you want to add an answer of your own I can remove that part.

Comment: These all work fine, but still run the expensive view in the last select (at least on 9.5). The middle lateral join is needed to go from 1 matching record in the first query to zero in the third (actual view) so that third view is never executed if it doesn't need to. The planner insists on running that view if any field of it is mentioned in the main select (it's the "json" field), despite the conditions.

Comment: Does a table values function help (sort of a parameterized view)? I'll add an example.

Comment: That seems to skip the view indeed (I added a pg_sleep in the view to make that extra clear). But is there a way to get the same result without wrapping all my views in functions? I guess this shows the filter conditions are ignored because the main query needs something (`json`) from the view and doesn't realize it's not going to get it...

Comment: I'm afraid my knowledge of PostgreSQL is very limited so I have no idea why it can't deduce this from a `LATERAL JOIN`, perhaps someone with greater insight will join (sorry, could not resist:-). If you look at the article I commented on in your question, there are a couple of algebraic optimizations that psql does not do. Regarding your question about wrapping views in functions, another option is to replace the view with a function.

Comment: Funnily enough, explicitly replacing a false `owner = "..."` condition with a literal `false` does skip the second query... So one boolean doesn't behave as another.

Comment: I created a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6882c6/5) to make it easier to see what's gong on.